# Cakephp HTTP Option request problems

Tags: php, ajax, cakephp, authentication

I am having some problems when it comes to handling basic authentication inside my Cake app. I have got to the point where I am sending an ajax request with an authorization header which has got my username and password base64 encoded.

This request is being sent to Cake, however when it is sent it is doing some preflighting as my Cake app is on a different host. When it does this preflighting my GET request becomes a OPTION request and I'm not exactly sure how to handle this in Cake. Any ideas on how to get this working?

This is my Ajax request:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#ajaxRequest').click(function() {
        var username = 'Useracct'
        var password = 'password'
        var tok = username + ':' + password;
        var hash = Base64.encode(tok);
        var authstring = "Basic " + hash;

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "json",
            data: {request: "ajax"},
            url: "http://wurx/users/login",
            beforeSend: function(xhr){
                xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", authstring);
            },
            success: function(data){
                console.log(data)
            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                console.log(xhr);
                console.log(ajaxOptions);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix this issue by including some response headers, as the request was cross-domain:

```
$this->response->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
$this->response->header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization");
```